# Open SSL make not working

Tags: environment-variables, make, ssl, openssl

I am trying to get openssl 1.1.1 so I can use TLS 1.3 with nginx, below is my code as well as the error

Best I can figure is that `LIBRPATH` is empty and that would cause the issue but I can't seem to find what value I should have it set to.

**Code:**

```
  tar xvf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
  cd openssl-1.1.1
  ./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'
  make
  make install
  cp /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
  echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Error**

```
./config -Wl,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1 (0x1010100fL) for linux-x86_64
Using os-specific seed configuration
Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   If you want to report a building issue, please include the   ***
***   output from this command:                                    ***
***                                                                ***
***     perl configdata.pm --dump                                  ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
```

**Output of perl script: perl configdata.pm --dump**

```
Command line (with current working directory = .):

    /usr/bin/perl ./Configure linux-x86_64 -Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)

Perl information:

    /usr/bin/perl
    5.22.1 for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Enabled features:

    afalgeng
    aria
    asm
    async
    autoalginit
    autoerrinit
    autoload-config
    bf
    blake2
    camellia
    capieng
    cast
    chacha
    cmac
    cms
    comp
    ct
    deprecated
    des
    dgram
    dh
    dsa
    dso
    dtls
    dynamic-engine
    ec
    ec2m
    ecdh
    ecdsa
    engine
    err
    filenames
    gost
    hw(-.+)?
    idea
    makedepend
    md4
    mdc2
    multiblock
    nextprotoneg
    ocb
    ocsp
    pic
    poly1305
    posix-io
    psk
    rc2
    rc4
    rdrand
    rfc3779
    rmd160
    scrypt
    seed
    shared
    siphash
    sm2
    sm3
    sm4
    sock
    srp
    srtp
    sse2
    ssl
    static-engine
    stdio
    tests
    threads
    tls
    ts
    ui-console
    whirlpool
    tls1
    tls1-method
    tls1_1
    tls1_1-method
    tls1_2
    tls1_2-method
    tls1_3
    dtls1
    dtls1-method
    dtls1_2
    dtls1_2-method

Disabled features:

    asan                    [default] OPENSSL_NO_ASAN
    crypto-mdebug           [default] OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG
    crypto-mdebug-backtrace [default] OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_BACKTRACE
    devcryptoeng            [default] OPENSSL_NO_DEVCRYPTOENG
    ec_nistp_64_gcc_128     [default] OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128
    egd                     [default] OPENSSL_NO_EGD
    external-tests          [default] OPENSSL_NO_EXTERNAL_TESTS
    fuzz-libfuzzer          [default] OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_LIBFUZZER
    fuzz-afl                [default] OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_AFL
    heartbeats              [default] OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS
    md2                     [default] OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip crypto/md2)
    msan                    [default] OPENSSL_NO_MSAN
    rc5                     [default] OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip crypto/rc5)
    sctp                    [default] OPENSSL_NO_SCTP
    ssl-trace               [default] OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE
    ubsan                   [default] OPENSSL_NO_UBSAN
    unit-test               [default] OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST
    weak-ssl-ciphers        [default] OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS
    zlib                    [default] 
    zlib-dynamic            [default] 
    ssl3                    [default] OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
    ssl3-method             [default] OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD

Config target attributes:

    AR => "ar",
    ARFLAGS => "r",
    CC => "gcc",
    CFLAGS => "-Wall -O3",
    CXX => "g++",
    CXXFLAGS => "-Wall -O3",
    HASHBANGPERL => "/usr/bin/env perl",
    RANLIB => "ranlib",
    RC => "windres",
    aes_asm_src => "aes-x86_64.s vpaes-x86_64.s bsaes-x86_64.s aesni-x86_64.s aesni-sha1-x86_64.s aesni-sha256-x86_64.s aesni-mb-x86_64.s",
    aes_obj => "aes-x86_64.o vpaes-x86_64.o bsaes-x86_64.o aesni-x86_64.o aesni-sha1-x86_64.o aesni-sha256-x86_64.o aesni-mb-x86_64.o",
    apps_aux_src => "",
    apps_init_src => "",
    apps_obj => "",
    bf_asm_src => "bf_enc.c",
    bf_obj => "bf_enc.o",
    bn_asm_src => "asm/x86_64-gcc.c x86_64-mont.s x86_64-mont5.s x86_64-gf2m.s rsaz_exp.c rsaz-x86_64.s rsaz-avx2.s",
    bn_obj => "asm/x86_64-gcc.o x86_64-mont.o x86_64-mont5.o x86_64-gf2m.o rsaz_exp.o rsaz-x86_64.o rsaz-avx2.o",
    bn_ops => "SIXTY_FOUR_BIT_LONG",
    build_file => "Makefile",
    build_scheme => [ "unified", "unix" ],
    cast_asm_src => "c_enc.c",
    cast_obj => "c_enc.o",
    cflags => "-pthread -m64",
    chacha_asm_src => "chacha-x86_64.s",
    chacha_obj => "chacha-x86_64.o",
    cmll_asm_src => "cmll-x86_64.s cmll_misc.c",
    cmll_obj => "cmll-x86_64.o cmll_misc.o",
    cppflags => "",
    cpuid_asm_src => "x86_64cpuid.s",
    cpuid_obj => "x86_64cpuid.o",
    cxxflags => "-std=c++11 -pthread -m64",
    defines => [  ],
    des_asm_src => "des_enc.c fcrypt_b.c",
    des_obj => "des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o",
    disable => [  ],
    dso_extension => ".so",
    dso_scheme => "dlfcn",
    ec_asm_src => "ecp_nistz256.c ecp_nistz256-x86_64.s x25519-x86_64.s",
    ec_obj => "ecp_nistz256.o ecp_nistz256-x86_64.o x25519-x86_64.o",
    enable => [ "afalgeng" ],
    ex_libs => "-ldl -pthread",
    exe_extension => "",
    includes => [  ],
    keccak1600_asm_src => "keccak1600-x86_64.s",
    keccak1600_obj => "keccak1600-x86_64.o",
    lflags => "",
    lib_cflags => "",
    lib_cppflags => "-DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN",
    lib_defines => [  ],
    md5_asm_src => "md5-x86_64.s",
    md5_obj => "md5-x86_64.o",
    modes_asm_src => "ghash-x86_64.s aesni-gcm-x86_64.s",
    modes_obj => "ghash-x86_64.o aesni-gcm-x86_64.o",
    module_cflags => "-fPIC",
    module_cxxflags => "",
    module_ldflags => "-Wl,-znodelete -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic",
    multilib => "64",
    padlock_asm_src => "e_padlock-x86_64.s",
    padlock_obj => "e_padlock-x86_64.o",
    perlasm_scheme => "elf",
    poly1305_asm_src => "poly1305-x86_64.s",
    poly1305_obj => "poly1305-x86_64.o",
    rc4_asm_src => "rc4-x86_64.s rc4-md5-x86_64.s",
    rc4_obj => "rc4-x86_64.o rc4-md5-x86_64.o",
    rc5_asm_src => "rc5_enc.c",
    rc5_obj => "rc5_enc.o",
    rmd160_asm_src => "",
    rmd160_obj => "",
    sha1_asm_src => "sha1-x86_64.s sha256-x86_64.s sha512-x86_64.s sha1-mb-x86_64.s sha256-mb-x86_64.s",
    sha1_obj => "sha1-x86_64.o sha256-x86_64.o sha512-x86_64.o sha1-mb-x86_64.o sha256-mb-x86_64.o",
    shared_cflag => "-fPIC",
    shared_defflag => "-Wl,--version-script=",
    shared_defines => [  ],
    shared_extension => ".so.\$(SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER)",
    shared_extension_simple => ".so",
    shared_ldflag => "-Wl,-znodelete -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic",
    shared_rcflag => "",
    shared_sonameflag => "-Wl,-soname=",
    shared_target => "linux-shared",
    thread_defines => [  ],
    thread_scheme => "pthreads",
    unistd => "<unistd.h>",
    uplink_aux_src => "",
    uplink_obj => "",
    wp_asm_src => "wp-x86_64.s",
    wp_obj => "wp-x86_64.o",

Recorded environment:

    AR = 
    BUILDFILE = 
    CC = 
    CROSS_COMPILE = 
    CXX = 
    HASHBANGPERL = 
    OPENSSL_LOCAL_CONFIG_DIR = 
    PERL = 
    RANLIB = 
    RC = 
    WINDRES = 
    __CNF_CFLAGS = 
    __CNF_CPPDEFINES = 
    __CNF_CPPFLAGS = 
    __CNF_CPPINCLUDES = 
    __CNF_CXXFLAGS = 
    __CNF_LDFLAGS = 
    __CNF_LDLIBS = 

Makevars:

    AR              = ar
    ARFLAGS         = r
    CC              = gcc
    CFLAGS          = -Wall -O3
    CPPDEFINES      = 
    CPPFLAGS        = 
    CPPINCLUDES     = 
    CXX             = g++
    CXXFLAGS        = -Wall -O3
    HASHBANGPERL    = /usr/bin/env perl
    LDFLAGS         = -Wl,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)
    LDLIBS          = 
    PERL            = /usr/bin/perl
    RANLIB          = ranlib
    RC              = windres

NOTE: These variables only represent the configuration view.  The build file
template may have processed these variables further, please have a look at the
build file for more exact data:
    Makefile

build file:

    Makefile

build file templates:

    Configurations/common0.tmpl
    Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl
    Configurations/common.tmpl
```

Comment: *"... as well as the error"* - there is no error included in your  "Error" output. This is just the expected output from config.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's expected? Doesn't look like it and that is the only step that shows anything even close to an error. Rest go fine but that one does not. What could be wrong then if that is not the error? Is the ENV variable in the command that produces the 'error' meant to me blank?

Comment: What do you mean with *"What could be wrong"*? You don't show any problem where something goes wrong. All you claim is *"make not working"* without any kind of proof and details what exactly is not working. What did you try, what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I thought my post was pretty straight forward, this is my commands used, this is the issue and this is the output. I expected it to have openssl work without issues which it does not. Not sure what else you would expect from those commands. I've tried the commands in the OP without luck and they seem to be standard across all online guides I have found. I get nothing when I do `openssl version`

Comment: @JoshKirby if there were errors when you ran `make` or `make install`, then please [edit] your question to include them - at the moment, all we have is the output of the `./config` command - which looks like it completed without error (ending with `Creating Makefile`)

Comment: @steeldriver Okay maybe I don't get it but I have never had this issue before. I see this site is not going to be of much help even with all available information provided other than I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS It is a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 with build-essentials and some other standard packages as well as the source for nginx downloaded but not compiled.

Comment: @JoshKirby if instead of typing `perl configdata.pm --dump` after the banner, you type `make` what happens? You should see a bunch of `gcc` commands scroll past

Comment: @steeldriver I see that gcc stuff goes by yes though it never works after I do all steps. Meaning it show blank for `openssl version`

Comment: What do you get if you type `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./apps/openssl version` from the `openssl-1.1.1` directory?